# Longest chain of digits in $\pi$.

Tags: pi

What is the longest chain of same digits in $\pi$?

This question comes into my mind while reading about the **Feynman Point** in a book. So is there any longest known chain? Like $999999$ of Feynman point.

Comment: Pretty sure that no one knows the answer. If $\pi$ is normal like it is conjectured to be, then there is no longest chain.

Comment: I mean just like Feynman point, are there similar chains known uptill or those six $9$s are the longest?

Comment: Play with http://www.angio.net/pi/piquery.html. You will see

Comment: On what base???

Comment: If the decimals are truly random, as they seem to be, then any sequence of digits of length K appears every 10^K digits on average, without any limitation on K.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Playing on [this site](http://www.angio.net/pi/piquery.html), I reproduced below the longest string of repeated numbers, the position and number of times they appear in the first 200 million of digits of $\pi$

```
 00000000  172330850  2
 11111111  159090113  3 
 22222222  175820910  1 
 33333333   36488176  1 
 44444444   22931745  2 
 55555555  168743355  1 
666666666   45681781  1 
777777777   24658601  1 
888888888   46663520  1 
 99999999   66780105  1
```

The problem is that 200 million is quite small when compared to the [12.1 trillion](http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-12t/) digits available since December 2013.

Have a look at [this page](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62868/what-is-the-longest-known-sequence-of-consecutive-zeros-in-pi) for more impressive answers.

Taken from [Fabrice Bellard](http://bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/pidigits.html) page (2.7 trillion digits), the longest repetitions (digit, length, position); this is much more impressive than with the poor 200 million digits.

```
0  12  1755524129973
1  12  1041032609981
2  12  1479132847647
3  12  1379574176590
4  12  1379889220413
5  12  1618922020656
6  12  1221587715177
7  12   368299898266
8  13  2164164669332
9  12   897831316556
```